# How to find the connected device after BLE scan

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, tizen, batterylevel

When performing a BLE scan using startScan(onFoundBLEDevice, onBLEScanError). First, is the parameter sent to onFoundBLEDevice a single device or is it a list of devices?  And if the answer is "single device" what happens when there is more than one BLE device in the local vicinity when performing the scan?

Secondly, Since my goal is to retrieve the battery level from my own smartphone (the one that is paired AND connected to my smartwatch) how can I tell which of the devices found by my scan is the one that's connected?  Or do I even need to perform a scan? Is there another way to retrieve the device object in order to then get the battery service 0x180F and then the battery level characteristic, 0x2a19?  In other words, I want to be sure that the battery level I retrieve is that of my phone, not my buddies sitting next to me.

UPDATE: my smartphone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3 and my smartwatch is a Samsung Gear S2 running Tizen 2.3.1.  I'm using Tizen Bluetooth API.

Comment: You should mention which platform and API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The BluetoothLEScanCallback (In your case onFoundBLEDevice) is invoked everytime a device is found. (For 3 nearby devices -> 3 calls)

I've scanned nearby devices from my gear while it's connected with a Mobile through 'Samsung Gear' app. No, There's no way to distinguish specific Mobile connected via Gear Manager from other devices. So, You can't find the connected device in this procedure. (Unless you are developing the app for personal use, In that case you can hardcode your Mobile device's UUID)

Samsung Provides 'Accessory' SDK for such purposes.

[Samsung Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory)

Any data you exchange using Accessory SDK would provide you info of specific 'The Connected' device via Samsung Gear. Check Out the API References, Programming Guides and Android-End Sample apps and Tizen-End Sample apps in Accessory SDK section.

Comment: Thanks - I think what I'll be able to do is use a conventional Bluetooth method (getKnownDevices) to store the MAC address of the connected device...then, I can compare the MAC address to those devices I find via BLE scan... in this way *I think* I'll be able to determine which device is my connected device and then thru subsequent BLE methods, get the batter service, level, etc... thanks for your answer!